# Axios.get not requesting anything

Tags: javascript, html, axios, frontend, backend

I'm trying to use axios to receive data from my backend to my front end so that my webpage can display the data but my axios does not even seem to even run the axios.get code.

```js
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081"
axios.get(`${baseUrl}/travels`)
.then((response) => {
const listing = response.data;
console.log(response.data)
})
```

That's my front end. There was no console.log or anything

```js
app.get('/travels', function (req, res) {
    listings.getListings(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status = 500;
            res.send(null);
        } else {
            res.status(200);
            res.send(result);
            
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my backend

Comment: try to add `cors` package?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Did you checked network tab for the request?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is a cors problem within your webserver since you are accessing a URL from a completely different project.

Install the following:

```sh
> npm install cors -S
```

Then in your express code put this:

```js
...
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
...
```

With this you are allowing your webserver to serve the resources to any project outside of itself.

**Note: put this code in your backend.**